# Al cargar archivos al servidor el sweetalert se cierra inmediatamente después de pulsar el botón

Tags: javascript, html

Éste es el formulario donde se cargan los datos de los archivos al servidor. Al dar clic en el siguiente botón:

```
<input class="image2" type="image" src="../Imagenes/mas.png"
    id="btnAgregarArchivo" alt="mas" />
```

Éste es el código HTML:

```
<form id="formArchivos" name="formArchivos" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <p class="barra2">
         <input class="miboton2" type="file" name="nuevoArchivo[]" id="nuevoArchivo[]" multiple=""/>
         <input class="image2" type="image" src="../Imagenes/mas.png" id="btnAgregarArchivo" alt="mas"/>
      </p> 
</form>
<script src="../../Libreria/Bootstrap4/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Libreria/Bootstrap4/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/gestorDocumentos.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnAgregarArchivo').click(function() {
        agregarArchivosGestor();
    });
});
</script>
```

Aquí está la función donde se carga la respuesta del sweetalert:

```
function agregarArchivosGestor(){
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('formArchivos'));
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../Controlador/Documentos/guardarArchivos.php",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "html",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(respuesta) {
            console.log(respuesta);
            respuesta = respuesta.trim();
             if(respuesta == 1){
                 swal(":D","Agregado con exito","success");
             } else {
                 swal(":(","Fallo al agregar","error");
             }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Con que "se cierra inmediatamente", ¿te refieres a que se recarga la página dejando mostrar ese mensajes apenas unos instantes?

Comment: Si correcto eso es lo que ocurre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo único que te falta es cancelar la propagación del evento al formulario con [`Event/preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

```
$('#btnAgregarArchivo').click(function(evento) {
    evento.preventDefault();
    agregarArchivosGestor();
});
```

Sin esa cancelación, inmediatamente tras la ejecución de `agregarArchivosGestor()` continuaría con la secuencia del envío del formulario, provocando la recarga de la página.

Además, te recomendaría capturar el evento de envío del formulario y no el de pulsar en el botón. Existen numerosas formas de enviar el formulario (como pulsar <kbd>ENTER</kbd> en un campo de texto) que se gestionan en un único evento en el campo del formulario (`<form>`):

```
$('#formArchivos').click(function(evento) {
    evento.preventDefault();
    agregarArchivosGestor();
});
```

---

Tu código podría quedar así:

```js
function agregarArchivosGestor() {
    var formData = new FormData(
        document.getElementById('formArchivos')
    );
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../Controlador/Documentos/guardarArchivos.php",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "html",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(respuesta) {
            console.log(respuesta);
            respuesta = respuesta.trim();
            if (respuesta == 1) {
                swal(":D", "Agregado con exito", "success");
            } else {
                swal(":(", "Fallo al agregar", "error");
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            swal(":(", "Fallo en la petición", "error");
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js" integrity="sha512-AA1Bzp5Q0K1KanKKmvN/4d3IRKVlv9PYgwFPvm32nPO6QS8yH1HO7LbgB1pgiOxPtfeg5zEn2ba64MUcqJx6CA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form id="formArchivos" name="formArchivos" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <p class="barra2">
    <input class="miboton2" type="file" name="nuevoArchivo[]" id="nuevoArchivo[]" multiple="" />
    <button class="image2" id="btnAgregarArchivo">✚</button>
  </p> 
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#formArchivos').click(function(evento) {
          evento.preventDefault();
          agregarArchivosGestor();
      });
  });
</script>
```

He capturado el evento `error` para gestionar problemas con la petición (como ocurre en este fragmento de código).

Comment: Muchas gracias Oscar el fragmento de código que funciono fue `$('#btnAgregarArchivo').click(function(evento) {
    evento.preventDefault();
    agregarArchivosGestor();});`  ya que el `$('#formArchivos').click(function(evento) {
    evento.preventDefault();
    agregarArchivosGestor();
});` y  la respuesta `,
        error: function() {
            swal(":(", "Fallo en la petición", "error");
        }` no me permitió cargar la función con el `buttom`

Comment: Lo importante era, como indiqué, `preventDefault()`. Me alegra que te funcionara. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta para darla por respondida.